# Filter inner query by the results of the outer query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Let me start in plain english first
Query: Get top 100 paying users and their current active item (just one item)

Here is a drafted query

```
SELECT `user_id`, SUM(p.`amount`) as `total`
FROM `users_purcahse` AS p
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT `ui`.`item_id` as `item_id`,  `ui`.`user_id` as `user_id`
                FROM `user_items` AS `ui`
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN `items` AS `i` ON  `ui`.`item_id` = `i`.`id`
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` AS `cat` ON `i`.`category_id` = `cat`.`id`
                WHERE `ui`.isActive = 1
) AS `ui` ON p.`user_id` = `ui`.`user_id`


GROUP BY `user_id`, `ui`.`item_id`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The problem with this is that the inner query is getting all users items table and then it will join it with the top 100 paying users

user items is a very large table, the query is taking too long
I simply want to attach the current active items for each user after doing the calculations

Note: a user can have so many items but only 1 active item
Note2: it's not enforced on the DB level that user_items can have one column with is_active per user

Comment: If your server version is 8.0.14 or above then use [LATERAL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html). This allows you to refer to the columns of above source table.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know this existed, this could be helpful indeed, However, I don't need to reference ant column in the outer projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for some well-chosen subqueries.

First, let's find the `user_id` values of your top-paying users.

```sql
                SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) total
                  FROM users_purcahse
                 ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
                 LIMIT 100
```

Next, let's find the `item_id` values for your users. If more than one item is active, we'll take the one with the smallest `item_id` value to get just one.

```sql
               SELECT user_id, MIN(item_id) item_id
                 FROM user_items
                WHERE isActive = 1
                GROUP BY user_id
```

Then, in an outer query we can fetch the details of your items.

```sql
SELECT top_users.user_id, top_users.total, 
       active_items.item_id,
       items.*, categories.*
  FROM (
                SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) total
                  FROM users_purcahse
                 ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
                 LIMIT 100
       ) top_users
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT user_id, MIN(item_id) item_id
                 FROM user_items
                WHERE isActive = 1
                GROUP BY user_id
       ) active_items ON top_users.user_id = active_items.user_id
  LEFT JOIN items ON active_items.item_id = item.id
  LEFT JOIN categories ON item.category_id = categories.id
 ORDER BY top_users.total DESC, top_users.user_id
```

The trick here is to use GROUP BY subqueries to get the data items where you need just one value per `user_id`.

Once you have the resultset you need, you can use `EXPLAIN` to help you sort out any performance problems.

Comment: we went for almost exact match for this query and it worked perfectly, thank you for your help